# Enable/disable network connection from command line

Tags: networking, cmd, windows-xp

I know that there exists ton of results in Google for this: [results](https://www.google.com.tr/?q=netsh%20interface%20set%20interface%20disabled#q=netsh%20interface%20set%20interface%20disabled), but I didn't make it in my Windows XP machine. I want to disable LAN connection from command line.

```
>netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" DISABLED
One or more essential parameters not specified
The syntax supplied for this command is not valid. Check help for the correct sy
ntax.

>netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin="disabled"
One or more essential parameters not specified
The syntax supplied for this command is not valid. Check help for the correct sy
ntax.

>netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=DISABLED
One or more essential parameters not specified
The syntax supplied for this command is not valid. Check help for the correct sy
ntax.
```

Comment: first let me ask why you are doing this? second if your are trying to disable LAN why not set it in the control panel

Comment: Because two LANs doesn't work together. So I eed to fisable one if them. I don't want to disable it manually I need to disable enable automatically with bat file.

Comment: okay I see where you are going let me look at some stuff and I let ya know.

Comment: @Arya, check out my answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831023/enable-disable-network-connection-from-command-line/30555518#30555518), I hope it helps.

Answer (score 25):

***For the first two commands, you need elevated/ administrator rights:***

**Disable the LAN network connection**

```
C:\> netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=disabled
```

**Enable the LAN network connection**

```
C:\> netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=enabled
```

**assumption :** your interface was named as "Local Area Connection" else substitute proper name. Use `netsh interface show interface` to find the name.

**List Wifi profiles**

```
C:\> netsh wlan show profiles
```

**Connect to Wifi profile**

```
C:\> netsh wlan connect name="ProfileName"
```

Comment: When run without elevated/ admin privileges, the first command fails, claiming "An interface with this name is not registered with the router.".

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without admin privileges?

Answer (score 6):

You have to run it with **elevated/ admin privileges**.

(On Windows 7, I otherwise get the confusing error message

> `An interface with this name is not registered with the router.`

)

<sub>(I edited @yarish kumar's answer to reflect this.)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh interface show interface

### Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name

Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Ethernet 2
Enabled        Disconnected   Dedicated        Ethernet
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Wi-Fi

C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh interface set interface name="Ethernet" admin=enable or disable

w10 output this..

Answer (score 1):

okay it looks like you need to delete the profile from the table. I.E.

netsh LAN>delete "profile of LAN connection"

before this you should save the configuration info of the LAN in case you want to ADD it back it will save as an XML file then to add it back just do

netsh LAN>ADD file-name="profile1.XML" interface="Local Area Connection"

also look at http://www.computerhope.com/netsh.htm for more details about netsh commands

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

1. Start a Command Prompt as administrator.
2. To show a list with 'Interface(s) Names', 'States' and more, type the following:

   > netsh interface show interface

It will echo something should like this.

```
> netsh interface show interface

Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Local Area Connection
Disabled       Disconnected   Dedicated        Local Area Connection 4
```

3. Now, pick an 'Interface Name' from your list.
   *for example, as you can see, mine is 'Local Area Connection'*

To **ENABLE** the selected connection type the following:

*Where is "%InterfaceName%" place your Interface Name. **Beware**: Close the 'Interface Name' in double quotes ["] if includes spaces, like mine for example: "Local Area Connection".*

```
netsh interface set interface "%InterfaceName%" ENABLE
```

OR if doesn't work for you, try the next:

```
netsh interface set interface name="%InterfaceName%" admin=ENABLED
```

To **DISABLE** the selected connection type the following:

```
 netsh interface set interface "%InterfaceName%" DISABLE
```

OR if doesn't work for you, try the next:

```
netsh interface set interface name="%InterfaceName%" admin=DISABLED
```

TIP: You can make a 'Restart Connection.cmd' or 'Restart Connection.bat' to do the job with just a double click. ;)
This could be like this:

```
@echo off
mode con: cols=80 lines=27
title Connection Restart
color 1f
cls
echo  This program restarts Internet Connection adapter.
echo.
echo  List of network adapters (Internet adapters)
netsh interface show interface
echo ==========================================================================

:: Setting Interface Name
set InterfaceName=Local Area Connection

:Disadling adapter
echo. & echo
echo  RESTARTING "%InterfaceName%" adapter. WAIT...
netsh interface set interface "%InterfaceName%" disable
echo "%InterfaceName%" adapter disabled. Wait...
echo. & echo.==========
timeout /t 5 >nul

:Enabling adapter
netsh interface set interface "%InterfaceName%" enable
echo "%InterfaceName%" adapter Enabled. Wait...
echo. & echo.==========
echo  Procedure completed successfully

timeout /t 6 >nul
EXIT
```

**Note** that the only thing you need to Replace in this Batch to make it work for you is the (exact) name of your **'Interface Name'** in the 13th line.

For example, the name in BOLD:
set InterfaceName=**Local Area Connection**.

This line (13th) makes this variable "%InterfaceName%" so you don't need to change anything else to work. But you would experiment if you like.

Enjoy